# making a snake pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a project for my cs class, its a snake game using pygame and i am really struggling through this project and this class in general. I am really trying to learn this stuff because i do think its interesting but its hard when you have the pressure of deadlines. i am working on a function called get_initial_snake. so as you can imagine its basically creating the game environment and then placing the snake in the game environment. heres my code

```
def get_initial_snake(snake_length,width,height,block_size):
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    background_colour = (250,250,250)
    window.fill(background_colour)
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*(block_size+1), y*(block_size+1), block_size, block_size)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,0,0), rect)
            pygame.display.flip()
```

so this is creating the black background with a white grid overtop of it. now i am trying to write code that will make the snake using the following parameters parameters. The initial snake is expected to be in the center of the screen.
More specifically:
If there are odd number of squares in the columns:
Then the snake head must be exactly in the middle row.
If there are even number of squares in the columns:
Then the snake head must be (num_rows / 2) th row.
Similarly,
If there are odd number of squares in the rows:
Then the snake head must be exactly in the middle column.
If there are even number of squares in the rows:
Then the snake head must be (num_cols / 2) th column. is there anyone that can give me insight into how this would be done in a generic fashion so that any parameters can be inputted and the snake would come out in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
def find_midpoint(length):
    from math import ceil
    return ceil(length / 2.0)  # dividing by 2.0 forces python to do floating point division
```

The starting row and starting column can then be calculated as

```
start_row = find_midpoint(height)
start_col = find_midpoint(width)
```

Since the `find_midpoint` function returns a floating-point number, you have to apply the `int()` function on the result if you *need* the result to be an integer.
**i.e.:** `start_row_as_int = int(find_midpoint(height))`

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly the easiest way to create a snake game. No images needed :).
Code:

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2, sw/2]
w.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)

key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    if snake[0][0] in [0, sh] or snake[0][1]  in [0, sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        curses.endwin()
        quit()

    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0] += 1
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1] += 1

    snake.insert(0, new_head)

    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
            nf = [
                random.randint(1, sh-1),
                random.randint(1, sw-1)
            ]
            food = nf if nf not in snake else None
        w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
    else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(int(tail[0]), int(tail[1]), ' ')

    w.addch(int(snake[0][0]), int(snake[0][1]), curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

To run the game, just type in `python [filename]`

Credit to [engineer man's "Creating a Snake game with Python in under 5 minutes"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbasThWVb-c)